# Clicking the username redirects to the revision history in CW posts

Tags: discussion, bug, community-wiki, revisions-list

When using the mobile site, clicking the username of the OP redirects to the edit history of the post while it should redirect to the profile page of the user (as it normaly does in the full site).

Is this bydesign?

Comment: This is by design; CW posts usually have more than one author. This happens on the full site as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks please post this as an answer.

Comment: This is a dupe, actually. :-)